# Using a separate front page layout with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, layout

Most parts of my application share a common layout including a header, sidenav and content area.  These common elements are set up in my `index.html` file, and the result of a rendered route is included via the `ng-view` directive.  See below.  (Note that I am trying to use Material Design also).

```
<body layout="row">    

    <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-whiteframe-z2">    
        <header>
            <!-- heading -->
        </header>    
        <ul>
            <!-- menu options -->
        </ul>    
    </md-sidenav>

    <div flex layout="column">
        <md-toolbar layout="row">
            <!-- tool bar content -->
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-content flex layout-padding id="content">
            <div ng-view></div>  <!-- result goes here -->
        </md-content>
    </div>    

    <!-- scripts --> 

</body>
```

My question is, how do I go about creating a front page which has a completely different layout, for example it does not have a side navigation?  It seems to me that I need to move the header, sidenav etc into a separate template, and then conditionally inject the result of a route into the separate template, before it is used in `ng-view`.  In other words, I think I need to conditionally decorate the route response.

Where do I start with this?

I see that there is a UI-router module available but I think this is probably overkill for my simple scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `ng-if` might help ... set a variable only in your home page controller so the condition will be false for all other routes.

```
<md-sidenav ng-if="!homePageControllerVariable">
```

Another alternative is a dynamic `ng-include`